# how to filter data from two data base table in django

Tags: django, sqlite

if two database table in django models.
how to get latest data from both tabels.
and print the order_by('date')

first database table:

```
class ANI_News_Detail(models.Model): # Represents ANI News Detail Model
    read_time=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=12, default=0.00)
    news_id=models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='News-title')
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='slug')
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='tags')
    category_name=models.ForeignKey(news_category,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
 
 
 sub_category_name=models.ForeignKey(news_sub_category,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    image_banner=models.URLField(max_length = 200)
    medium_thumbnail=models.URLField(max_length = 200)
    content = RichTextField() # Field Used For Paragraphs
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

2 database table

```
class News_Detail(models.Model): # Represents Our News Detail Model
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    read_time=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=12, default=0.00)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='News-title')
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True)
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='tags')
    category_name=models.ForeignKey(news_category,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    sub_category_name=models.ForeignKey(news_sub_category,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    image_banner= models.FileField(upload_to='image_banner', blank=True, null=True)
    medium_thumbnail = models.FileField(upload_to='medium_thumbnail', blank=True, null=True)
    content = RichTextField() # RichTextField is used for paragraphs
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: `ANI_News_Detail.objects.order_by('created_at')` and `News_Detail.objects.order_by('created_at')`?

Comment: how to print both data in a single queryset

Comment: You have two separate models and they are not related, you can’t get them in a single queryset

Answer (score 0):

You definitely should not combine two different QuerySets. But you can do it another way. As I can see both models have exactly same argument to be ordered in. You can get all object into same `list`, then sort list with `lambda` by `.created_at`.

```
mix = []
ani_news = ANI_News_Detail.objects.all()
news = News_Detail.objects.all()

[mix.append(an) for an in ani_news]
[mix.append(n) for n in news]

sorted_mix = sorted(mix, key=lambda x: x.created_at)

if you want reverse the order:
sorted_mix = sorted(mix, key=lambda x: x.created_at, reverse=True)
```

Comment: Thank you NixonSparrow.  it's working fine.....

Comment: Great! Consider marking the answer as the correct one. It makes it clearer for another helpers.